# Format timestamp value using Spark Dataframe API

Tags: date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a Dataframe with a `date` **column representing Unix timestamp in `String` format**. The column values need to be formatted to a different String representation as below -

Input Dataframe

```
+----+----+-------------+
|name|code|         date|
+----+----+-------------+
|   A|   1|1545905416000|
|   B|   3|1545905416000|
|   C|   5|1545905416000|
+----+----+-------------+
```

Expected output Dataframe

```
+----+----+-------------+
|name|code|         date|
+----+----+-------------+
|   A|   1|   2018-12-27|
|   B|   3|   2018-12-27|
|   C|   5|   2018-12-27|
+----+----+-------------+
```

This didn't work as it is giving `null` for all values -

```
 peopleDFCsv.withColumn("formatted_date", 
            functions.date_format(functions.col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
            .show();
```

Comment: Or [Scala: Spark SQL to_date(unix_timestamp) returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40433065/10465355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_format) function works with timestamp not milliseconds since epoch. Try doing the conversion with CAST:

```
df.withColumn("formatted_date",
  functions.date_format(expr("CAST(date/1000 AS TIMESTAMP)"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  .show()

//    Outputs:
//    +----+----+-------------+--------------+
//    |name|code|         date|formatted_date|
//    +----+----+-------------+--------------+
//    |   A|   1|1545905416000|    2018-12-27|
//    |   B|   3|1545905416000|    2018-12-27|
//    |   C|   5|1545905416000|    2018-12-27|
//    +----+----+-------------+--------------+
```

The reason why you are getting `null` is because date_format is interpreting your string as a timestamp such as `"2018-12-27 11:10:16"`. The plain number of does not conform to the format it expects so it just returns null.